# Specifying DataContext in XAML and using it for binding in the next attribute

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Consider the following code:

```
<MyControl DataContext="{Binding DataObject}" Text="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
```

As far as I know, XAML attributes are assigned by the order they are declared. However, XML-wise, depending on it is a bad design. I guess I could rewrite it to look like so:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding DataObject}">
    <MyControl Text="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
</Grid>
```

However, putting a Grid just for semantics seems wrong to me.

What do you think?

Thanks!
Vitaly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your question. The order in which those attributes are set doesn't really make a difference. When the text attribute is set to the binding as you've done it, all it does is create a Binding that is tied to the Text property and has a Path of "DisplayText". As long as the DataContext is set at the time that the binding is *evaluated* (which occurs sometime later) then you're fine.

Comment: Oh.. I see what you're saying. But do all the binding evaluations necessarily occur after the properties are set? I guess it makes sense that they do, but I am unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Grid is not recommended anyway cause it's effect performance, if you have no chiose(no parent to put context in) use a border

Comment: Interesting to know @ Grid vs Border. However, how do you estimate the performance of them? Is there any source for that? Thanks!